# NGRX Store. Cannot assign to read only property '18' of object '[object Array]'

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, frontend, ngrx

When I'm trying to create ngrx store I'm getting 7 errors.

TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property '18' of object '[object Array]' | TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'incompleteFirstPass' of object '[object Object]' | TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value')

reducer.ts

```
import { createReducer, on } from '@ngrx/store';
import { Fields } from '../fields.model';

import { addAllFields } from './fields.action';

export const initialState: Readonly<Fields> = {
  arrStart: [],
  arrEnd: [],
};

export const fieldsReducer = createReducer(
  initialState,
  on(addAllFields, (state, { extArr }) => {
    return { ...state, arrStart: extArr };
  })
);
```

actions.ts

```
import { TemplateRef } from '@angular/core';
import { createAction, props } from '@ngrx/store';

export const addAllFields = createAction(
  '[Fields Array]Add fields to starting array',
  props<{ extArr: TemplateRef<any>[] }>()
);
```

fields.model.ts

```
import { TemplateRef } from '@angular/core';

export interface Fields {
  arrStart: TemplateRef<any>[] | null;
  arrEnd: TemplateRef<any>[] | null;
}
```

I know that state must be immutable, and because of this, I return a copy of my current state.

I have dispatch in my component and there must be a problem. console.log(fieldsArr) returns 2 TemplateRef

```
constructor(private store: Store) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    const fieldsArr: TemplateRef<any>[] = [this.inputField, this.textareaField];
    console.log(fieldsArr);

    this.store.dispatch(addAllFields({ extArr: fieldsArr }));
  }
```

Comment: I want to create 2 arrays with TemplateRefs and then exchange Reft within these 2 arrays. But firstly I want to write some starting Refs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is probably the `TemplateRef`, because these are dispatched to the store, these will be frozen. I'm not 100% sure, but my guess is that Angular mutates the `TemplateRef` on change detection. Because this is the same instance as the one that is frozen by the store, this error is thrown.

Comment: So, what can I do to prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 0):

The TemplateRef will be mutated which is forbidden by the architecture of NGRX.
If you want to use TemplateRef in ngrx/store, you should deactivate rules of mutation for ngrx like this :

```
StoreModule.forRoot({}, {
                runtimeChecks: {
                  strictStateImmutability: false,
                  strictActionImmutability: false,
                }
              }),
```